# Any way to speed up this Perl script?

Tags: perl

I have this script which combines two texts based on the identical parts.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

my $f1 = 'input.txt';
my $f2 = 'add.txt';
my $f3 = 'output.txt';

my %ids;
my $fh;

open $fh, '<', $f2 or die "Can't read the file with replacements: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    my ($name, $id) = split /=/;
    $ids{$name} = $id;
}
close $fh;

open my $fho, '>', $f3 or die "Can't write output file: $!";
open $fh, '<', $f1 or die "Can't read input file: $!";
while (<$fh>) {
    for my $name (keys %ids) {
        s/$name/${name} $ids{$name}/;
    }
    print $fho $_;
}

close $fh;
close $fho;
```

For example.

input.txt - "text stream" without particular structure

```
random text random text, TARGET TEXT 1 — random
textTARGET TEXT 2! random text random text
random text random text random text
TARGET TEXT 3 random text random text TARGET TEXT 4 random text
```

add.txt - list of text to add

```
TARGET TEXT 1=ADDITIONAL TEXT 1
TARGET TEXT 2=ADDITIONAL TEXT 2
TARGET TEXT 3=ADDITIONAL TEXT 3
TARGET TEXT 4=ADDITIONAL TEXT 4
```

output.txt will be:

```
random text random text, TARGET TEXT 1 ADDITIONAL TEXT 1 — random
textTARGET TEXT 2 ADDITIONAL TEXT 2! random text random text
random text random text random text
TARGET TEXT 3 ADDITIONAL TEXT 3 random text random text TARGET TEXT 4 ADDITIONAL TEXT 4
```

I have a fairly large text files to combine (~40Mb) and the script doing its work super slow. Is there any way to speed it up? Or maybe someone knows a tool that can do the exact same thing.

Comment: You have a subtle bug. If a line contains the same key twice only the first one will be replaced.  Your `s///` needs a `/g` to fix this.

Comment: `split` permits a "limit" argument permitting you to stop searching for the split character after you find it. This would speed up the first loop a bit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loops with in loops are always suspicious, especially when there's IO involved.

```
while (<$fh>) {
    for my $name (keys %ids) {
        s/$name/${name} $ids{$name}/;
    }
    print $fho $_;
}
```

The best performance improvement you can do here is to not do it line by line.  Instead, read the whole file in and work on it as a single piece of text.  40 megs is not that much memory these days, if you read the whole file in as a single string you could do the whole thing once.  This eliminates a lot of Perl and IO overhead.

```
# Or use File::Slurp or Path::Tiny
my $text = do { local $/; <$fh> };

for my $name (keys %ids) {
    # The /g is important to replace all instances of each key
    $text =~ s/$name/${name} $ids{$name}/g;
}
print $fho $text;
```

Clever buffering could make this more memory efficient.  Rather than reading the whole file, you can use `read()` to read the file in large blocks while still ensuring `$text` always ends on a newline.  That general technique for reading files deserves its own question and probably already has an answer, so I leave that to you.

---

Next improvement is to not loop over each key.  Instead, combine all the keys together into a single regex, get all the keys which match on each line, and apply them.  Use [Regex::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) to do the combining.

```
my $all_keys = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$all_keys->add( keys %ids );
my $all_keys_re = $all_keys->re;

# Get all the matched keys at once, the /g is important.
my @matches = $text =~ /($all_keys_re)/g;

# Replace all the matched keys. Use uniq to avoid doing the replacement twice.
for my $match (uniq @matches) {
    # Use /g to replace multiple copies of the same key on a line.
    $text =~ s/$match/$match $ids{$match}/g;
}
print $fho $text;
```

This will be a win if each file contains a low percentage of the total possible keys.  The regex will be significantly faster because it will use a more efficient algorithm than brute force rescanning the text for each key.  It will also be executed in the regex engine which is generally more efficient than Perl bytecode.

This can be made even more efficient by using the suggestions from the other answers and doing it all in a single `s///`.

```
my $text = do { local $/; <> };

$text =~ s{($all_keys_re)}{$1 $ids{$1}}g;

print $text;
```

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer. `my $text = do { local $/; <$fh> };` did its job. I've tested the script on a sample text and it works 21 times faster than before (14s vs 304s)! Also I tried to use Regex::Assemble, but for some reason this script works slower with it (39s).

Comment: Seven times as fast instead of 21 times might seem worthwhile if you discovered that the substitution for 'TARGET TEXT 1' also eats 'TARGET TEXT 10' and more. Just one example. Schwern is being a persistent wise voice about combining regular expressions - take heed.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate your patterns (keys) into a single large regex:

```
/(a|b|c|d|...|zzz)/
```

Compile the large regex once, and use the group `$1` as your key in a lookup.

```
s/$big_re/$1 . $addtext{$1}/ge;
```

(The `/e` flag makes the replacement an expression, not text. You are writing `$1 . $text` but may want to do other things within the expression (call a function, make it lower case, add more formatting, etc.). See docs [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#s%2f_PATTERN_%2f_REPLACEMENT_%2fmsixpodualngcer), look for `/e` flag in examples.

Comment: There are many subtle edge cases when combining a regex. I would highly recommend [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This bit you can speed up quite handily:

```
for my $name (keys %ids) {
    s/$name/${name} $ids{$name}/;
}
```

Compile it into a regex:

```
my $search = join "|", map {quotemeta} keys %ids; 
   $search = qr/\b($search)\b/;
```

And then in the loop:

```
s/$search/$1 $ids{$1}/g;
```

Note - I've added `\b` for word break matching, because that's less likely to trip you up with substrings and sort orders. Obviously, you don't need to.

But it means you're not then doing a loop of regex matches each iteration.

Comment: There are many subtle edge cases when combining a regex. I would highly recommend [Regexp::Assemble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Assemble) to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Though it might look plausible, the above answers have assumed that the application of the replace patterns is independent of the order of  **pattern**  defined in  **add.txt** .

The original question should be clarified more to answer correctly.

For example, `<b> input.txt </b> can be changed only once`, etc.

What if one pattern in  **add.txt**  changes some lines, and then the other pattern in  **add.txt**  changes the previously changed ones?